# Visual Studio 2013 force check of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Let me explain what I'm trying to do. So in SQL Management studio, you can click the checkmark box to have it refresh/evaluate your query before trying to execute the query.

What I'm wondering is if there is something similar in VS to do the same thing. Let me explain the scenario...

I had some code with calls to a function. I am removing this function to consolidate code. I know the function is called numerous times, so I commented the whole function. I knew without a doubt there would be errors, and along with that the color boxes for them *should* have shown up in my scroll bar.

Nothing did (either in error output window or scroll bar). So I ran a build (knowing it would fail) and of course it did with my error output now populated as well as my scroll bar.

Is there a similar functionality in VS that I am not aware of that will force not only the error window to output outstanding errors, but also force the scroll bar to update as well without doing an entire build (like SQL's check query)?

Comment: Just build your solution. Try CTRL-SHIFT-B. A full rebuild is not required.

Comment: Yeah that is what I did (ctrl shift B)- sorry not a clean/build or even a rebuild. I was wondering if there was a faster method (for example if I start entering Private Int myIntfxn(string a){ a = " } it will immediately show up in both places. Maybe it is a case of how much is affected it can't keep up (in this scenario)?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 a build is the only option. Things may change in Visual Studio 2014, when Roslyn is introduced.

Comment: Gotchya, thanks for feedback- if you want to throw it into an answer I'll mark it- Or I'll delete if not later this afternoon. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 a build (CTRL-SHIFT-B) is the only option. A full rebuild works as well of course, but is not required.

Things may change in Visual Studio 2014, when Roslyn is introduced.